# How can we get all array elements in Mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a classroom collection structured  as

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("517a54a69de5ee980b000003"),
  "class_name" : "A",
  "students" : [{
    "sname" : "John",
    "age" : "13"
  }, {
    "sname" : "Marry",
    "age" : "12"
  }, {
    "sname" : "Gora",
    "age" : "12"
  }]
}
```

With php, I like to get and list all students based on class _id . How can we do it?

**UPDATE** The query I use:

```
$student_list=$collection->find(array(" rid"=>new MongoId($theObjId )), 
        array(
            "students" => 1,
        )
        );
```

I want to print it out all the list of the students. I could not manage it by using Foreach loop.

Comment: do a json_encode and you will get an array. then you can loop through key / val

Comment: You mean you don't know how to query and return students by class_id?

Comment: @Satya : json_encode do the work. Can we do it without json_encode?

Comment: @Satya : +1 for json_encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$student_list is a MongoCursor of multiple rows. You need to loop through that to get access to the row you're looking for. Like so:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("_id"=>new MongoId($theObjId)), 
        array("students" => 1));

foreach($cursor as $row)
    foreach($row['students'] as $student)
         echo $student["sname"], $student["age"];
```

Also, consider using [findOne](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php). It is better suited to your query.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is call `findOne()` instead of `find()`:

```
$classroom = $collection->findOne(
  array( '_id' => new MongoId($theObjId )), 
  array( 'students' => 1 )
);

$classroom['students']; // will be an array of students
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php

Comment: Thanks, this also did the job.